# Problems in detect an exception thrown in the render response phase using a class that specializes ExceptionHandlerWrapper

Tags: jsf, primefaces, mojarra

I'm trying to implement a mechanism for global exception handling in JSF through specialization of the abstract classes `ExceptionHandlerWrapper` and `ExceptionHandlerFactory`. However, when an exception is thrown in the render response phase of the JSF lifecycle, it is not stacked (***Phase.queueException*** is never called) and hence is not captured in the ***handle*** method of the class that specializes `ExceptionHandlerWrapper`.

The following code fragments summarize the situation where the mentioned problem occurs.

JSF:

```
<h:form id="formManterLider">
    <h:selectOneMenu>
        ...
        <p:ajax update=":formManterLider" listener="#{MB.atualizarListaLideresInstituicao}" />
        ...
    </h:selectOneMenu>

    <p:dataTable value="#{MB.lazyModel}" ... />
</h:form>
```

Java:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MB {
    ...
    private LazyDataModel<LiderVO> lazyModel = new LazyDataModel<LiderVO>() {
        @Override
        public List<LiderVO> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters) {
            ...
            List<LiderVO> lista = consultarLideresCandidatos(getInstituicaoSelecionada(), first, pageSize); // throws a RuntimeException
            return lista;
        }
    };
}
```

Changing the selection value in the `h:selectOneMenu` component through an AJAX request triggers the problem, because the statement `update=":formManterLider"` causes the method `load` to be invoked during the render response phase, and the method `consultarLideresCandidatos`, which is invoked within the `load` method, throws a `RuntimeException`.

I would like to know how to detect an exception thrown in the render response phase using a class that specializes `ExceptionHandlerWrapper`.

Note: I'm using Mojarra 2.1.12 and Primefaces 3.2.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue (LazyDataModel + exception in the render phase). Try Mojarra 2.1.16 or greater.
See http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2179

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know how to detect an exception thrown in the render response phase using a class that specializes ExceptionHandlerWrapper.

Don't have a clue, but doesn't the server's log suffice as this is where stack traces are dumped?

To prevent the exception being thrown (and you want to update the data table only) you can update the data table directly:

```
<h:form id="formManterLider">
    <h:selectOneMenu>
        ...
        <p:ajax update=":formManterLider:datatable" listener="#{MB.atualizarListaLideresInstituicao}" />
        ...
    </h:selectOneMenu>

    <p:dataTable id="datatable" value="#{MB.lazyModel}" ... />
</h:form>
```

Comment: Only the server logs aren't enough, because I want to redirect the user (or replace the page that was rendered incorrectly during processing of ajax request) to an error page.

Update only the table doesn't solve the problem, because the load method is invoked in the same way during the render response.

But thanks for the reply!